# Does oclint on windows work?

Tags: windows, oclint

I'm running the windows binary distribution of oclint. Using cmake with CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON I create a compile_commands.json. Here are the first 2 entries:

```
[
{
  "directory": "C:/QtCassandra/src",
  "command": "c:/MinGW/bin/c++.c++.exe -Ic:/QtCassandra/include -Ic:/Users/mwest/src/libQtCassandra-0.3.2/include   -DQtCassandra_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/QtCassandra.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles/QtCassandra.dir/QCassandra.cpp.obj -c C:/Users/mwest/src/libQtCassandra-0.3.2/src/QCassandra.cpp",
  "file": "C:/Users/mwest/src/libQtCassandra-0.3.2/src/QCassandra.cpp"
},
{
  "directory": "C:/QtCassandra/src",
  "command": "c:/MinGW/bin/c++.c++.exe -Ic:/QtCassandra/include -Ic:/Users/mwest.PARASOFT/src/libQtCassandra-0.3.2/include   -DQtCassandra_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/QtCassandra.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles/QtCassandra.dir/QCassandraPrivate.cpp.obj -c C:/Users/mwest/src/libQtCassandra-0.3.2/src/QCassandraPrivate.cpp",
  "file": "C:/Users/mwest/src/libQtCassandra-0.3.2/src/QCassandraPrivate.cpp"
}
```

Then I attempt to run oclint for a single source file and get this

:2685340:0: error reading 'C:UsersmwestsrclibQtCassandra-0.3.2srcQCassandra.cpp'

```
OCLint Report

Summary: TotalFiles=0 FilesWithViolations=0 P1=0 P2=0 P3=0 


[OCLint (http://oclint.org) v0.8]
```

I've tried several things, using escaped slashes and backslashes on the command line and editing the command file in the same way. No matter which combination I use I still get this error. Is this a known oclint on windows issue? Would it help if I built it from the source?

Is this an issue with oclint? Has anyone made it work with Windows 7?